# ADFS set up in windows server 2022

Tags: windows, adfs, windows-server-2022

I'm trying to set up ADFS for windows server 2022 to authorize users (active directory) in a web application that will only be used over the local network.

I set up my windows server 2022 machine my first installing ADCS and then following the instructions here to create an SSL certificate:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn781428(v=ws.11)

In the case of this microsoft page, under the section "Request and enroll a new SSL certificate for AD FS" it says to set common name and and alternative name to the FQDN. I don't have an external FQDN so I set it to my win22 server machine name on the domain i.e. win22name.domainname.local

Then I install ADFS (on the same machine) and when I install my first federation server (on the same win 22 server machine) it asks me for my certificate I import the certificate I created. After installation I get the message:

"An error occurred during an attempt to set the SPN for the specified service account. Set the SPN for the service account manually.  For more information about setting the SPN of the service account manually, see the AD FS Deployment Guide.  Error message: The SPN required for this Federation Service is already set on another Active Directory account.  Choose a different Federation Service name and try again."

I am able to access https://localhost/adfs/.well-known/openid-configuration but I can't access https://win22name.domainname.local/adfs/.well-known/openid-configuration.

I then uninstalled everything and tried again, but this time for FQDN I just used some random FQDN (fs.myfqdn.com) and the installation doesn't prompt me with an error. What's the correct way to do this? I don't have an FQDN and I just want to use ADFS locally over the network to authorize this web app.

For background info, the web app will also be hosted on this server (using kestrel) and I am using identityserver and adfs as the oidc provider.